# How do I move an XMLRPC software to ZMQ?

Tags: zeromq

Hello the software in question works with XMLRCP, the communication is bi-directional since the server needs to know the status of the client to give him orders, then there are many clients controlled by one or more servers. Clients are currently consulting who they should listen to through a "DNS Server" that is always running. The application is to control the clients from a monitor, this can activate, deactivate, send messages, etc ...

What architecture in ZMQ could replace or make this model more efficient? The problem is that having so many customers generates a bottleneck that slows down the application.

With ZMQ is it possible to do without this "DNS Server"?

Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what you're intending to do, it's hard to say what would be best. Have you seen this XMLRPC implementation done over ZMQ? https://github.com/alex8224/zmqxmlrpc

Comment: Well, this software does what I said, consists of two elements, clients and servers, each client will be controlled by one or more servers and the server also needs to know the status of the clients to know what orders they can send. Basically it is software that we use to lend computers in a room, but you can control that room from the main office.